# I work on four PCs. How do I move unstaged (or staged) but uncommitted files from one machine to another with or without pushes?

Tags: git

Git project. I work on four PCs. How to move unstaged (or staged) but uncommitted files from one pc to another with or without pushes?

I don't want a lot of pushes just for moving files around. I need a way to fix the problem in my branch, moving around during the day from one pc to another without pushes online. How to?

Or maybe I can push and then pull in another PC and "undo" the changes to have again my files in staged (or unstaged) area (maybe with `git reset --soft`?).

How can I do?

Comment: Your use of Git perplexes me to no end.  You're on multiple machines, but all of those machines have access to the same repository.  The remote repository then becomes the absolute source of truth in terms of the code and its state.  Why *wouldn't* you want to push the changes up?  You can always overwrite/squash them together later with `git rebase -i`.

Comment: Why not just...work on a temporary branch, that you can push and rebase and modify to your heart's content, and then neaten everything up before committing on your primary branch? Why are you trying to avoid the facilities that already exist for moving changes between different repositories?

Comment: You can sneakernet your changes with bundles.

Comment: So essentially you want to push without pushing?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use git for anything you must conform to the git way of thinking.  This mean that in order for git to know about a file, it must be committed, and in order for one repository to know what goes on in another repository (for example on another machine) you must either push or fetch updates to bring the two repositories in sync.

If you do not want to do that, you simply cannot use git for this.  Instead use all the normal options available regarding synchronizing files between computers.

Note that you *can* do a lot of commits on a branch containing your work in progress, and when done and merging up, you can create a single "squash" commit containing all the work and all the intermediate commits will then be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you do have to commit if you want to use `git push`/`git pull` to transfer data. That doesn't mean you have to pollute history doing this though: you can commit and push to a temporary branch, and then clean up your history (`git rebase -i` and friends, read the docs before you use it as it is a potentially destructive command, `merge --squash` as the other answer suggests, ...).

The alternative is to use something other than Git itself to transfer uncommitted files, including untracked files. Tools like [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/index.html) or [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) are very good for that.